# Calculate Time left for Device to be fully Charged android

Tags: c#, android, battery

I have an activity that contains a TextView that should show the time left for the android device that is plugged in to be fully charged...
I used BatteryManager class to achieve this...i created an object from that class and discovered there is a method called `ComputeChargeTimeRemaining`
Only problem is that the result of that method is of the data type long, and i don't know how to convert this data type to time values... That's exactly why I decided to reach out for help... Here is the code am using to do it...

```
class Notes : AppCompatActivity{
//TextView to show remaining charge time
TextView mytext;
//Timer to update the value of the TextView every Second 
System.Timers.Timer _timer;
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle SavedInstanceState){
  mytext=(TextView)FindViewById(Resource.Id.textView1);
_timer=new System.Timers.Timer(1000);
_timer.Enabled =true;
_timer.Elapsed += Timer_Elapsed;
  } 
private void Timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e) {
RunOnUiThread(()=>{
BatteryManager batteryManager=(BatteryManager)GetSystemService(Context.BatteryService);
long remaining_time=batteryManager.ComputeRemainingChargeTime();
//Here is where I have a problem converting the long to real hours,minutes time format, please help
}) ;
} 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's visit the documentation:

[computeChargeTimeRemaining](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/BatteryManager#computeChargeTimeRemaining())

> Compute an approximation for how much time (**in milliseconds**)
> remains until the battery is fully charged. Returns -1 if no time can
> be computed: either there is not enough current data to make a
> decision or the battery is currently discharging.

So how can we deal with it?

A [`TimeSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=net-5.0) should do

```
var timeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(remaining_time);
```

Now you have the features of `TimeSpan` likes `Hours`, `Minutes`, `Seconds`. `TotalMinutes` etc, you also have the format specifiers [Standard TimeSpan format strings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/standard-timespan-format-strings):

```cs
    var hours timeSpan.Hours;
    var minutes = timeSpan.Minutes;
    // or
    var str = timespan.ToString("hh\\:mm\\:ss"));
```

Comment: Post the whole solution that will display the minutes and the hour please...

Comment: How can i detect if charger is connected

Comment: @CoderTimothy that is a different question. If you ask another question someone is bound to answer